# Want to add users to an array and display it dynamically in a table using angular and javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a beginner at javascript and angularjs and was recently coding to display all the users in my array in a table and have them update dynamically as I add more users through a form... however when I run my code all I get is "Fill out the entire form!". I was hoping you guys could tell me what I am doing wrong (most importantly) and how I could fix it.

Thanks!

My HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" class="align-center"><input type="text" placeholder="Search Users" class="search-users" ng-click="userSearch"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="add-user" id="formFirstName" /></td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="add-user" id="formLastName" /></td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Race" class="add-user" id="formRace" />    </td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Class" class="add-user" id="formClass" /></td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Faction" class="add-user" id="formFaction" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" class="align-right error-field" id="errorField"></td>
<td colspan="1" class="align-right"><button type="button" class="add-user" ng-click="addUser()"/> Add </button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My Javascript/Angular:

```
$scope.jsFirstName = document.getElementById('formFirstName').value;
$scope.jsLastName = document.getElementById('formLastName').value;
$scope.jsRace = document.getElementById('formRace').value;
$scope.jsClass = document.getElementById('formClass').value;
$scope.jsFaction = document.getElementById('formFaction').value;
$scope.jsID = users.length;
$scope.addUser = function () {
    $scope.character = {};
    $scope.character.id = $scope.jsID+1;
    $scope.character.firstName = $scope.jsFirstName;
    $scope.character.lastName = $scope.jsLastName;
    $scope.character.faction = $scope.jsFaction;
    $scope.character.class = $scope.jsClass;
    $scope.character.race = $scope.jsRace;

    if ($scope.jsFirstName.length === 0 || $scope.jsLastName.length === 0 || $scope.jsFaction.length === 0 || $scope.jsClass.length === 0 || $scope.jsRace.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById('errorField').innerHTML = "Fill out the entire form!";
    } else {
        users.push(character);
    }

};

});
```

Comment: You should never use `document.getElementById` within a controller. Please read more tutorials about angularjs because it is not the way you should handle things.

Comment: You need *Fill out the entire form!*

Comment: I've made a similar answer here, there's also a plunkr in case it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40604553/2398593

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using AngularJS, you should use ng-model directive to pass the data from the view to controller instead of doing it manually using Javascript. So, you should never use `document.getElementById` within a controller.

These changes you have to made in your code :

1. add ng-model directive in each input type.
2. pass all the `form data` inside an `object` using `ng-model`.

**Ex :**

```
<td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="add-user" ng-model="user.formFirstName" id="formFirstName" /></td>
```

Here, I created `user` object and then we can pass this whole object using ng-click="addUser(user)".

**Working demo :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('userController',function($scope) {
    $scope.usersData = [];
    $scope.addUser = function(user) {
      $scope.usersData.push(user);
      $scope.user = {};
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userController">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="add-user" ng-model="user.formFirstName" id="formFirstName" /></td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="add-user" ng-model="user.formLastName" id="formLastName" /></td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Race" class="add-user" ng-model="user.formRace" id="formRace" />    </td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Class" class="add-user" ng-model="user.formClass" id="formClass" /></td>
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Faction" class="add-user" ng-model="user.formFaction" id="formFaction" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1" class="align-right">
<input type="button" class="add-user" ng-click="addUser(user)" value="Add User"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>First Name</td>
  <td>Last Name</td>
  <td>Race</td>
  <td>Class</td>
  <td>Faction</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="users in usersData">
  <td>{{users.formFirstName}}</td>
  <td>{{users.formLastName}}</td>
  <td>{{users.formRace}}</td>
  <td>{{users.formClass}}</td>
  <td>{{users.formFaction}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Since you use angular, you should not do what you do.

Let's take an exemple out of your code : `FirstName` :

```
<td><input type="text" id="formFirstName" ng-model="firstName" /></td>
<!-- Others like this -->

<td ng-bind="errorField"></td>
<!-- OR INSTEAD -->
<td>{{errorField}}</td>
```

Now you should have a controller, right ? So, in your controller, you can do this :

```
$scope.addUser = function() {
    $scope.character = {};
    $scope.character.firstName = $scope.firstName;
    // Others like this

    if($scope.firstName === "") { // More conditions
        $scope.errorField="Please fill out the form";
    }
}
```

This is why Angular has been made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular use 2 way data binding. Add ng-modal="fromFirstName" .... Etc to your inputs . In your controller set up local variable like var firstname = $scope.formFirstName . As it's 2 way data binding in real time you views and models are changed. When the user clicks the button you can check for emptiness. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myusersList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.users = [{fname:"sj",lname:"rao",class:"10"},{fname:"fvsdf",lname:"sdf",class:"1120"}];
    $scope.addUser = function () {
        var newUser = {};
        newUser.fname=$scope.fname;
newUser.lname=$scope.lname;
newUser.class=$scope.class;
        $scope.users.push(newUser);
    }
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myusersList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="data in users">First Name : {{data.fname}} last Name : {{data.lname}} class : {{data.class}}</li>
  </ul>
  <input ng-model="fname">
  <input ng-model="lname">
  <input ng-model="class">
  <button ng-click="addUser()">Add</button>
</div>

<p>Write in the input field to add users.</p>

</body>
</html>
```